# Smooth conversion between color image to greyscale

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I would like to smoothly convert an RGB image to greyscale as a function of some *continuous* `parameter`. I have seen plenty of posts on how to convert 3-channel to 1-channel, but that would not work for me, I would like the output to still be 3-channels. Is this possible?

I would like to have a function

```
f(image, parameter)
```

that does more or less the following: if `paramater` is zero, the function returns the original `image`, and if the `parameter` is one it returns a greyscale image. Therefore, I would have the ability to smoothly tune the color between on and off via `parameter`.

If there already is a coded solution, in Python is strongly preferred.
Thanks!

Comment: 1 channel means grayscale and 3 channels means rgb.. I don't think you can have a grayscale output be 3 channels

Comment: @ankitbatra22 it's actually easy, you can create a 3-channel image where r=g=b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite easy to do with [PIL/Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(r'c:\temp\temp.jpg')
gray = im.copy().convert('L').convert('RGB')
im2 = Image.blend(im, gray, 0.75)
```